# returning two values

Tags: asp.net

How can I modify this:

```
if ( reader.GetString( reader.GetOrdinal( "Status" ) ) == "Yes" )
{
    return true; // Return Status + Date it was Completed
}
else
{
    return false; // Return Status + null Date.
}
```

To return two values?  Currently it returns the column 'Status' from the database with the value of Yes or No.  How can I have it return the completed date and the status?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    private void DoSomething() {
        string input = "test";
        string secondValue = "oldSecondValue";
        string thirdValue = "another old value";
        string value = Get2Values(input, out secondValue, out thirdValue);
        //Now value is equal to the input and secondValue is "Hello World"
        //The thirdValue is "Hello universe"
    }

    public string Get2Values(string input, out string secondValue, out string thirdValue) {
        //The out-parameters must be set befor the method is left
        secondValue = "Hello World";
        thirdValue = "Hello universe";
        return input;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion is the best way to do this, to write a class or a struct for the result.

Otherwise you could use out-parameter

Comment: can you please give an exaqmple

Comment: for which way? class/struct or out-parameter?

Comment: IS there no way to return an object, so on the otherside that is calling this I could do.  

`if (rtnVal.Status)
{
    lbl.text = rtnVal.CompletedDate
}`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small example:

```
    private void DoSomething() {
        string input = "test";
        string secondValue = "oldSecondValue";
        string value = Get2Values(input, out secondValue);
        //Now value is equal to the input and secondValue is "Hello World"
    }

    public string Get2Values(string input, out string secondValue) {
        //The out-parameter must be set befor the method is left
        secondValue = "Hello World";
        return input;
    }
```

Comment: befor you call the method with the out-parameter you create a new paramter. this parameter you give to the function with the keyword 'out'. it's like you give a reference to the object. In the method you can work with the parameter. After leaving the method the parameter has a new value

Comment: thanks so much! can you please tell me in which situation would we use the OUT? why wouldnt we just "normalize" it into regular code like an object with two properties or something?

Comment: In my opinion the code is easier to read if you use classes for multiple-return-types. i also use the out-parameter in scenarios where i don't need the class at any other place.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably best to define a `struct` with two properties, but if you really don't want to do that you could use the generic `KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>` struct:

```
        KeyValuePair<bool, DateTime?> result;
        if (reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Status")) == "Yes")
        {
            result = new KeyValuePair<bool, DateTime?>
                (true, DateTime.Now); // but put your date here
        }
        else
        {
            result = new KeyValuePair<bool, DateTime?>
                (false, null);
        }
        // reader.Close()?
        return result;
```

`KeyValuePair` has two properties, `Key` and `Value`. Key will be your status and Value will be your date.

Note, you'll need to use [nullable DateTime](http://www.dotnetperls.com/nullable-datetime) if you need a null date.

Comment: I am looking up information on structs, it looks very promising but I will need to practice with them.  Thank you for the answer. :)